# Efficiently compare each element of a numeric vector to the previous element

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to generate intertime values - given a vector of say, 20, 30, 69, 89, 200, what's the difference between each pair?

The dataset has 25m elements, so I looked at both R and RCpp for a solution - speed is important. The R implementation was:

```
intertime <- function(x){

    output <- x[2:length(x)] - x[1:(length(x)-1)]
    return(output)
}
```

The C++ implementation:

```
NumericVector intertime(NumericVector timestamps) {

  //Identify size of input object
  int input_size = timestamps.size();

  //Instantiate output object
  NumericVector output(input_size-1);

  //Loop over the data
  for(int i = 1; i < input_size;++i){

    //For each entry, the output value is [entry] minus [previous entry]
    output[i-1] = (timestamps[i] - timestamps[i-1]);

  }

  //Return
  return output;
}
```

The C++ implementation is ~1 order of magnitude faster than the R implementation. I appreciate that R is kind of optimised for vectorised operations, so the speed difference being so small shouldn't shock me *that* much, but: can anyone think of a decent way of performing these kind of operations within Rcpp/C++ that's more efficient?

Comment: I don't think I understand but could `diff(x)` be what you want?

Comment: I don't see an order of magnitude speed difference between the two functions. The Rcpp implementation is faster by a factor of 3 to 4 in my benchmarks, which I'd consider excellent (and which I find quite surprising). The operations you do in your R function are strongly optimized (and implemented in C). `diff` should be slower than your R function due to some additional checks.

Comment: Tyler: diff in R? Totally, but as Roland notes it's actually slower than the barebones R.

Comment: Roland: huh: interesting! How big is the input vector you're using?

Comment: I tried normal randoms of lengths 1e6 and 1e7.

Comment: The R function essentially does 2 copies of almost the entire input vector (due to the subsettings), which you avoid with Rcpp. That explains the performance difference.

Comment: @OliverKeyes I've long learned not to say something is slower or faster without benchmarking the results.  Roland used unsure language "should" whereas you quoted him using stronger "it's actually slower".  Have you benchmarked these?  If so sharing the benchmarks would be informative to the community.

Comment: Yep, using the microbenchmarks framework. Roland is correct about the 3/4 factors faster bit - not sure how I missed that. Results [here](https://gist.github.com/Ironholds/ee389e96272e4c16f3e3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard C++ there's [`std::adjacent_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/adjacent_difference/) for doing what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main () {
  int val[] = {1,2,3,5,9,11,12};
  int result[7];

  std::adjacent_difference (val, val+7, result);
  for(auto i : result) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37eec3625ca46dd3)

Comment: Neat! I'll see if I can integrate it with RCpp and get back to you :).

Comment: Hmn; it looks like Rcpp has "diff" as an equivalent piece of syntactic sugar. On my machine, at least, this is actually slightly *slower*, not faster.

Comment: @OliverKeyes not surprising, the impl of `diff` in Rcpp is a bit slow. The impl in `Rcpp11` is better.